# Cups not starting on bootup

Tags: printing, startup

I have installed cups on Ubuntu 18.04 and for some reason we ever I reboot the box it will not startup on bootup. To startup after boot I am having to run "sudo systemctl restart cups.service" and once I that all is good, but really need this to work on startup. Please advise.

Comment: Before you `sudo systemctl restart cups.serrvice`, what does ``service cups status` show? What log messages relating to CUPS from `journalctl -b 0`?

Comment: let me reboot now and then run service cups status and see what it shows. Give me a minute and I will back to you.

Comment: So I rebooted and when running the service cups status it shows running and when I do a ps -ef | grep cups it shows processes.  So maybe it is running now on reboot.